# Testing props.history in Mocha

Tags: typescript, testing, mocha.js, sinon, react-testing-library

I am trying to mock history.push using sinon stub in mocha.

```
describe('first stage',() =>{
  it('Calls with inputs from the user', async () =>{
      const string1='mail@gmail.com';
      const string2='Abcd1234';
      const historyPushStub = sinon.stub();
      render(<Page1 history={{push:historyPushStub}}/>);
      const email = screen.getByLabelText('email');
      fireEvent.change(email,{target :{value:string1}});
      const emailUpdated = screen.getByLabelText(email);
      assert.strictEqual(emailUpdated.getAttribute('value'),string1);
      const password = screen.getByLabelText('passwordLabel');
      fireEvent.change(password,{target :{value:string2}});
      const passwordUpdated = screen.getByLabelText('passwordLabel');
      assert.strictEqual(passwordUpdated.getAttribute('value'),string2);
      fireEvent.click(await screen.findByText('Enter'));
      assert.strictEqual(historyPushStub.args.length,1);
  });
});
```

The Page I am testing is :

```
type Page1Props = {
    history: any;
};

const Page1Page: React.FunctionComponent<Page1Props> = (props: Page1Props) => {
    const [username, setStateUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setStatePassword] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.history.push('/business');
     };

    return (
        <div className="page1">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Stack tokens={{ childrenGap: 8 }}>
                    <TextField
                        value={username}
                        onChange={(_e, val) => setUsername(val)}
                        type="email"
                        label="emailLabel"
                    />
                    <TextField
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(_e, val) => setPassword(val)}
                        label="passwordLabel"
                        type="password"
                    />
                    <PrimaryButton
                        type="submit"
                        text={'Enter'}
                    />
                </Stack>
              )}
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The historyPushStub.args.length is 0.What am I doing wrong?
The test reaches the handleSubmit, however the history stub doesn't contain anything.

Comment: Can't help without seeing the complete code under test

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example